# How to pass object into rabl partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rabl

I need to create a [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) partial, where I need access to an object. For Eg:-

```
# app/views/posts/index.rabl
collection @posts

node(false) { |post| partial('posts/show', :object => :post)}
```

Inside show.rabl

```
# app/views/posts/index.rabl
object @post

node(:details) do
  {:id => @post.id}
end
```

Gives me, **undefined method id for nil class**. What am I doing wrong? Even the documentation gives the same steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
locals[:object].id
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped. But, it would be really great if you can share some more detail about where did you get this syntax from?

Comment: Also, I'm not able to get any association record from this object. Eg: `locals[:object].user`

Comment: Try accessing the associated object using `root_object.user`